# video or photo filter suggestion

Tags: video-editor

How to edit a photo to look like this clip. [link](https://youtu.be/LU02p0eN1-Q?t=11m8s) On the video  you can see a pic with a background moving left to right and at the same time the light changing(bright/dark). I am not sure if its filter or something else. Any suggestion accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was possibly achieved by taking a picture from several different angles simultaneously with multiple cameras. You can then flip through the images like a flip book.

You can simulate this by taking a single still image and separating out the foreground (the people in this case) from the background. For example, in Photoshop you could use any selection method you want - lasso, pen tool, quick mask, etc. - to select the people. Cut them out and put them on another layer. Next, turn them off and fill in the area where they used to be with something believable. This is a case where content-aware fill comes in handy. Turn the layer with the people back on. Import the photo into any motion graphics application, but be sure to import it as separate layers and not a composite. Once in the app, move the people towards the camera and/or move the background away from the camera. Once there's some separation you can orbit the 3D camera around the image a little bit. If you go too far, it will become obvious that the people are a 2D cut-out, so be careful with how far you take it.

You can also apply lights to the image in the motion graphics application. That should help you get a look similar to what you saw in the link.